# ASP .NET Framework Web API HttpResponseException

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.8

I have the following code, for clarity's sake I took out everything that was irrelevant.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/AddAccount")]
    [ActionName("LoadNew")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddAccount()
    {
        using (var context = new AMLPContext())
        {
            using (var txn = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    // Step 1: check if Account ID already exists or not
                    var dataExists = context.Table1.Where(x => x.Account_ID == acc_id).Any();

                    if (dataExists)
                    {
                        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, $"Risk Case already exists"));
                    }

                    // Insert data into database
                    context.Table1.Add(riskDtl);
                    context.Table2.Add(riskHistDtl);

                    context.SaveChanges();

                    txn.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    txn.Rollback();
                    throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message));
                }
            }
        }

        return Ok(new { status = true });
    }
```

At Step 1 there, I am checking whether the ID already exists in DB or not. If it does, then it will throw the error 400 along with message. However in Visual Studio it keeps throwing this error and returning Error 500 in front-end:

> System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException: 'Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.'

I can't seem to figure out why it's throwing this error or what I am doing wrong in this case. Would really appreciate it if someone can point out my mistake.

Comment: Why is this method marked as `async` when you're never using `await` inside of it ?

Comment: @marc_s It is. I'm using `await Task.Run()` but I removed all the code that I deemed wasn't necessary to the issue I was having

Answer (score 0):

It's because you throw an exception, and don't catch it. The `HttpResponseException` turns out just an implementation of the `Exception` class, which means will return an Error 500 to indicate the problem is from the Internal Server.

The correct way to return a bad request resonpe would be:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, $"Risk Case already exists");
```

### Refactor

To refactor your code, I would add additional `catch` block like the below

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/AddAccount")]
    [ActionName("LoadNew")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddAccount()
    {
        using (var context = new AMLPContext())
        {
            using (var txn = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    // Step 1: check if Account ID already exists or not
                    var dataExists = context.Table1.Where(x => x.Account_ID == acc_id).Any();

                    if (dataExists)
                    {
                        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, $"Risk Case already exists"));
                    }

                    // Insert data into database
                    context.Table1.Add(riskDtl);
                    context.Table2.Add(riskHistDtl);

                    context.SaveChanges();

                    txn.Commit();
                }
                catch (HttpResponseException ex)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    txn.Rollback();
                    throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message));
                }
            }
        }

        return Ok(new { status = true });
    }
```

Comment: You are correct. But in your refactor, Why not just return a bad request response directly instead of catching the exception and then returnering bad request?

Comment: For further concern. In the future, you may want to make a service and then delegate the checking condition to that. You cannot return an `IActionResult` here, so you have to throw an `HttpResponseException`. The catch block is for that.

Comment: "You cannot return an IActionResult here".. That is very incorrect

Comment: "You cannot return an IActionResult here". Yes, I was incorrect. I was thinking about the scenario where I put the code in another project and that project doesn't refer the 
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace. Thank you for pointing out.